# How to Insert current Date into richtextbox in the current selected place?

Tags: c#, richtextbox

hi i need to insert the current date in a rtb in the current position Can you please help me!

i tried this

```
AppendText(Environment.NewLine + DateTime.Now.ToString(M/dd/yyyy));
```

but it adds the date in the end of the textbox but i dont want that i want it to be in the current selection position

Comment: Hi and Welcome to StackOverFlow, What do you mean by Current position, Please provide more detail or code.

Comment: This is the Right answer tb.SelectionLength = 0;
            tb.SelectedText = DateTime.Now.ToString("M/dd /yyyy"); Thanks @Denis Stukalov

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Answer is

```
tb.SelectionLength = 0;
tb.SelectedText = DateTime.Now.ToString("M/dd /yyyy");
```